# "Мерцание" BottomNavigationView при смене фрагментов

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-navigation-view

Суть проблемы: при замене одного фрагмента на другой в рамках одной вкладки в `BottomNavigationView` проиходит "мерцание" последнего. Происходит это только с одним фрагментом и только при замене его на какой-либо другой. При замене на него проблема не наблюдается. Разметка "проблемного" фрагмента ниже.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/background_material_light"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_group_info" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="#ccffffff"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/waPrimary"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/waPrimaryDark"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="@color/waPrimaryDark">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add_vote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_thumbs_up_down_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_label="Голосование"
            style="@style/MenuButtonsStyle" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add_announcement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_announcement_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_label="Объявление"
            style="@style/MenuButtonsStyle" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

В других фрагментах используется `LinearLayout` или `RelativeLayout`. Я так понимаю, что проблема именно в `CoordinatorLayout`. Возможно ли как-то избавиться от данного эффекта?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение - проблема оказалась в `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` у `CoordinatorLayout`. После того, как убрал этот атрибут, проблема с отрисовкой решилась.